# Tables and HTML5 markup

Tags: html, css

I am having problem with some basic HTML and CSS, I think it has to do with my HTML file, trying to figure out tables. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to make it look identical to my example. Below is the example that I am seeking.

CSS and HTML code:

```css
html {
  background: purple;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#pageWrapper {
  display: table;
  vertical-align: top;
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
  width: 800px;
  height: 40%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

nav {
  padding: 15px;
}

section {
  width: 200px;
  display: table-cell;
}

article {
  width: 550px;
  display: table-cell;
}

aside {
  width: 225px;
  display: table-cell;
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
}

#header {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: white;
}

nav ul {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
}

ul li a:link,
ul li a:visited {
  color: green;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #c8b99c;
}

RAW Paste Data html {
  background: purple;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#pageWrapper {
  display: table;
  vertical-align: top;
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
  width: 800px;
  height: 40%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

nav {
  padding: 15px;
}

section {
  width: 200px;
  display: table-cell;
}

article {
  width: 550px;
  display: table-cell;
}

aside {
  width: 225px;
  display: table-cell;
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
}

#header {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: white;
}

nav ul {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
}

ul li a:link,
ul li a:visited {
  color: green;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #c8b99c;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Credit 4 Practical</title>
  <link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="pageWrapper">
    <header>
      <img src="logo.jpg" width="301" height="91" alt="Kris Townsend: Educator">

      <nav>
        <ul>
          Home |
          <li><a href="#">Link 1</a> |</li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a> |</li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3</a> |</li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>


      <section>
        <p>
          <strong>First Column</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
          Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
        </p>
      </section>

      <article>
        <p>
          <strong>Article</strong> Vivamus facilisis tincidunt eleifend. Mauris ultricies consequat molestie. Nam congue lectus et augue condimentum eget tincidunt quam pretium. Mauris ullamcorper, justo eu pulvinar placerat, risus nulla faucibus ligula,
          non convallis erat massa ut erat. Proin porta feugiat dolor, sed consequat ante tristique et. Praesent ornare, odio in varius interdum, velit nisl sollicitudin urna, quis dapibus urna sapien eu neque. Maecenas bibendum, libero eu dictum semper,
          sem ipsum congue nisl, a mollis est quam in velit. Cras vitae ligula ut nunc viverra dapibus. Vivamus facilisis eros sit amet est mollis pellentesque. Ut quis odio vel urna ornare lacinia. Aliquam vel justo posuere purus vehicula aliquam. Duis
          ornare mollis nisi luctus suscipit. Sed viverra urna id enim malesuada ac ullamcorper risus sollicitudin. Maecenas faucibus tincidunt facilisis. Donec eu nibh ac metus aliquet imperdiet sit amet in eros. Ut ut nibh elit.
        </p>
      </article>

      <aside>
        <p>
          <strong>Aside</strong> Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril.
        </p>
      </aside>

      <footer>
        <strong>Footer</strong> The small print that goes in the footer. <a href="#h">This hyperlink should display as a normally formatted link.</a>
      </footer>

  </div>
  <!-- pageWrapper -->
</body>

</html>
```

I'm trying to be as basic as I can, I haven't been introduced to flex-box or anything like that.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Hi Bioxvirus, please include the code in the post itself, not just linking to third party sites. Also *"this is the example that i am seeking"* doesn't link to anything - did you forget to include something there? It's unclear what your end goal is.

Comment: where is the example that u are trying to simulate?

Comment: you dont have <table> in your html code, what part of your code do you want in a table?

Comment: Sorry i should be as clear as possible by table i  mean im being told to use "display: table;" and "display: table-cell;" to align three colums of content "article" "aside" "section" under the nav bar. this content is to have a different color than the background page and is to be smaller then the entire page. i suck so bad at this i really do appricate the replys back im trying my best to provide information i really want to understand why its not like the example i left at the end of my original post. im not html savy so my wording might not be up to par forgive me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   html {
    background-color: purple;
    }


body {
  width: 800px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
   background-color: white;
}

#pageWrapper {
  display: flex;
}

section, aside { flex: 1; } 
article { flex: 2; }

footer {
  text-align: center;
}

nav {
  padding: 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
}

ul li a:link,
ul li a:visited {
  color: green;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #c8b99c;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Credit 4 Practical</title>
<link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<header>
    <img src="logo.jpg" width="301" height="91" alt="Kris Townsend: Educator">
</header>

<nav>
    <ul>
        Home |
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a> |</li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a> |</li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a> |</li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div id="pageWrapper">
    <section>
        <p>
            <strong>First Column</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
            Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
        </p>
</section>

<article>
    <p>
        <strong>Article</strong> Vivamus facilisis tincidunt eleifend. Mauris ultricies consequat molestie. Nam congue lectus et augue condimentum eget tincidunt quam pretium. Mauris ullamcorper, justo eu pulvinar placerat, risus nulla faucibus ligula,
        non convallis erat massa ut erat. Proin porta feugiat dolor, sed consequat ante tristique et. Praesent ornare, odio in varius interdum, velit nisl sollicitudin urna, quis dapibus urna sapien eu neque. Maecenas bibendum, libero eu dictum semper,
        sem ipsum congue nisl, a mollis est quam in velit. Cras vitae ligula ut nunc viverra dapibus. Vivamus facilisis eros sit amet est mollis pellentesque. Ut quis odio vel urna ornare lacinia. Aliquam vel justo posuere purus vehicula aliquam. Duis
        ornare mollis nisi luctus suscipit. Sed viverra urna id enim malesuada ac ullamcorper risus sollicitudin. Maecenas faucibus tincidunt facilisis. Donec eu nibh ac metus aliquet imperdiet sit amet in eros. Ut ut nibh elit.
    </p>
</article>

    <aside>
        <p>
        <strong>Aside</strong> Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril.
        </p>
    </aside>
</div><!-- /pageWrapper -->

<footer>
    <strong>Footer</strong> The small print that goes in the footer. <a href="#h">This hyperlink should display as a normally formatted link.</a>
</footer>
</html>
```

this produced the example picture sorry that I was not more clear in my first response hope this is a proper response?....